# Property 'authorization' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Consider this code:

```js
  setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
    const token = await getToken(config.resources.gatewayApi.scopes)

    const completeHeader = {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization:
          token && token.accessToken ? `Bearer ${token.accessToken}` : '',
      } as Express.Request,
    }

    console.log('accessToken: ', completeHeader.headers.authorization)
    return completeHeader
  })
```

Which generates the following TS error:

> Property 'authorization' does not exist on type 'Request'.

This comes from trying to access `completeHeader.headers.authorization`. The property `authorization` is indeed not available on the `Express.request` interface. It's strange that TypeScript can't infere the type from the literal object, which clearly is of type `string`. When not defining the type `as Express.Request` an error is thrown about an unsafe any assignment.

Is it required to create a new TS interface just for this one field? Or are we using an incorrect type? The field `authorization` looks to be like a commonly used field for sending tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The reason is because you're coercing `completeHeader.headers` into the `Express.Request` type. *The coerced type overrides the inferred type.*

What you can do, is expand that coerced type by doing the following:

```
as Express.Request & { authorization: string }
```

or you could create an entirely new type:

```
type AuthorizedRequest = Express.Request & { authorization: string };
...
as AuthorizedRequest
```

Comment: I also tried `(token && token.accessToken ? `Bearer ${token.accessToken}` : '') as string` but that didn't work. Your suggestion is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I needed to add user & I got error in headers with authorization(req.headers.authorization), me resolve was:

Case 1:
1.1. Where was error(req.headers.authorization), but before i had got similar error but with user:

```
import { IAuthRequest } from "./../types/user.type";

const checkAuth =
    () => async (req: IAuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            //2. Second i got error here(main problem)
            //i got if, i set <req:IRequestUser> for resolve 
            //problem with <req.user>: Property 'authorization' 
            //does not exist on type 'Headers'.
            //And you need to change <req: IAuthRequest>, and 
            //resolve problems
            if (!req.headers.authorization) throw new Error("Please log in");

            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

            if (!process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                throw new Error("Please create <SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN> in .env file");

            const { decoded, expired } = Jwt.verifyJwtToken(
                token,
                process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN
            );

            if (expired) return res.status(401).send("Token has been expired");

            //1. first error here
            //before(Property 'authorization' does not exist on 
            //type 'Headers'.) i have got error here(Property 
            //'user' does not exist on type 'Request'.), if 
            //<req: Request>, you can try resolve this problem
            //<req: IRequestUser> and after this, i got error
            //with req.headers.authorization (see <2. Second i 
            //got error ...>, code above)
            req.user = decoded; 

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
        }
    };
```

1.2. In folder named like "types", i have created file <user.type.ts>
and added:

```
export interface IUserData {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    username: string;
}

export interface IRequestUser extends Request {
    user: IUserData;
}

export type IAuthRequest = IRequestUser & {
    headers: { authorization: string };
};
```

You need just delete comments and code above will work correctly, comment only for understanding what was in code before error, and how i resolve this problems

Case 2:
after a while I found an even easier way:

```
import { IAuthRequest } from "./../types/user.type";

const checkAuth =
    () => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            req as IAuthRequest;

            //your code...

            next();
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
        }
    };
```

i hope that maybe it will help to someone